# label generated by macro in LaTeX

Tags: macros, labels

I built myself a macro for some tables to get them all in the same style. In my document body I wanted to reference to some of these tables, so in my macro they get a label. Unfortunately it always says, even after I ran it a couple of times.

> Reference 'tab:mess-2_2f' on page 2 undefined

this is my macro:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\def\messwerte#1#2#3#4#5#6{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{#2\textwidth}
\begin{longtable}{c}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\rowcolors{2}{blue!20}{white}
\begin{tabular}{*{#1}{l|}l}
\rowcolor{blue!40}
#3
\\ \hline
#4
\end{tabular}
\\
\caption{#5}
\label{tab:mess-#6}
\end{longtable}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
}
```

in the document I used it like this:

```
\messwerte{1
}{0.4
}{$U$&\textbf{$n$ in \si[per-mode = reciprocal]{\min^{-1}}}
}{\num{110}&\num{2250}\\
\num{60}&\num{1310}\\
}{Messwerte
}{2_2f
}
```

an I tried to reference it like this:

```
\ref{tab:mess-2_2f}
```

Comment: Not related to \label, but why have you got a longtable inside a minipage? the only purpose of a longtable  is to allow page breaking, and the only purpose of a minipage is to prevent page breaking, minipage will win here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! (Untested, but) using `{2_2f<newline>}` is the same as `{2_2f<space>}`, so your label contains a trailing space. Remove the new line before the closing `}` and it should work.

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{colortbl}` from your code. `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
` already loads it. By the way, you should get an error message informing you about that. `\usepackage{pgfplots}\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` will also result in a option class error. Change the order to `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}` instead.

Comment: One possibility is that in your `\messwerte` invocation, there is an extra blank space inserted after `2_2f` and before the closing `}`.  That would give you something other than you might be thinking.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think it was because of the coloring. Had a problem with regular tables in this case and it worked out with the longtables, so I left it like this

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik oh okay, didn't know this. So of course it works now... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DraUX since it can't be "long" the only reason longtable in minipage doesn't generate an error is that I didn't think anyone would do it or think it was necessary to check for that and give an error, so it sort of works but .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
{2_2f
}
```

which generates `\label{tab:mess-2_2f }` not `\label{tab:mess-2_2f}`

Unrelated but all of

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{#2\textwidth}
\begin{longtable}{c}
```

could be replaced by

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
```

as the inner `minipage` isn't doing anything, and a `longtable` inside a `minipage` can not work, page breaking is disabled, but in this case it is a one-row, one column table, just containing a nested `tabular` so it is doing nothing other than allowing `\caption` via a very strange rout.

You could caption the table using

```
 \captionof{table}{#5}
```

from the (one-line) `caption-of` package.